# How to resolve this circular dependency in EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, circular-dependency

In my application, an `Agency` has many `Employees`, one of which is delegated the owner of said agency:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public int EmployerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EmployerId")]
    public virtual Agency Employer { get; set; }
}

public class Agency
{
    public int AgencyId { get; set; }
    public string AgencyName { get; set; }
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OwnerId")]
    public virtual Employee Owner { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Employer")]
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

I attempt to enter a new `Agency` into the datebase using this code:

```
var agency = new Agency();
// ... 

context.Agencies.Add(agency);

var owner = new Employee();
// ...

context.Employees.Add(owner);

owner.Employer = agency;
agency.Owner = owner;

context.SaveChanges();
```

When I call `SaveChanges`, I receive the following error which I assume is due to the circular dependency I described above:

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations.
>   Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model
>   requirements, or store-generated values.

Is there a way in EF to specify the order for the "dependent operation"? Alternatively, is there a better way to write my database such that it gets around this problem but still models the data structure I want?

Comment: does your actual DB schema look like what you are expecting?

Comment: yep, exactly how I was expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it would be possible at all to create agency and owner in SQL because to store the agency you need a valid FK to the owner and to store the owner you need a valid FK to the agency. Due to the FK constraints (unless they wouldn't be enforced) you can't store any of these without violating a constraint.

A solution (and I don't know another one) is making one of the relationships optional, for example the `Owner` by defining the `OwnerId` as nullable:

```
public int? OwnerId { get; set; }
```

This won't solve the "valid ordering" exception immediately but now you can store an agency without owner and then store the owner with the relationship to that already stored agency. To make the whole operation "atomic" you can wrap the two necessary calls to `SaveChanges` into an outer transaction:

```
using (var tx = new TransactionScope())
{
    var agency = new Agency();

    context.Agencies.Add(agency);

    context.SaveChanges(); // inner transaction 1
    // saves agency with OwnerId = NULL, it wouldn't work with a required owner
    // agency has a primary key from the database now

    var owner = new Employee();

    context.Employees.Add(owner);

    owner.Employer = agency; // sets FK EmployerId to the now known PK of agency
    agency.Owner = owner;

    context.SaveChanges(); // inner transaction 2

    tx.Complete(); // commits the outer transaction
}
```

Comment: Hmm, sad. I was trying to avoid a transaction as I read they can cause deadlocks with entity framework. Is the code above likely to cause any such issues?

Comment: @ajbeaven: Yes, the *default* isolation level of `TransactionScope` is rather restrictive (`Serializable`). But you can easily change it, for example to `Snapshot` which makes deadlocks much less likely: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/diego/archive/2012/04/01/tips-to-avoid-deadlocks-in-entity-framework-applications.aspx